# Make local storage that can't be changed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, storage

Is there a way to make local-storage (or some other client side storage) impossible for users to change in the dev tools? Say I have a feature in which the user needs to pay money for or complete a challenge to get, and the program wants to check if the user has that feature. How can I stop people from going into the developer tools and manually adding that feature?

Comment: _"How can I stop people from going into the developer tools and manually adding that feature?"_ - Don't store this info on the client...

Comment: First step - verify everything on the server.

Comment: You can't, it's your users' browser, and it's your users' LocalStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **indexedDB**, Which use can't modify by themself.

Code for Angular 9. I have use [localforage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localforage).

```js
import * as localforage from 'localforage';

// store particular key details
  setDataInIndexedDB(key, value) {
    return localforage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
      .then(() => { })
      .catch(() => { });
  }

  // fetch particular key details
  async getDataFromIndexedDB(key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      localforage.getItem(key)
        .then((result: any) => {
          resolve(JSON.parse(result));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }

  // For Remove Particular Field/Key
  removeDataFromIndexedDB(key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      localforage.removeItem(key)
        .then((result: any) => {
          const remove = 'Key Removed';
          return resolve(remove);
        }).catch((err) => {
          return reject(err);
        });
    });
  }

  // Database has been entirely deleted.
  clearDataFromIndexedDB() {
    return localforage.clear();
  }
```

[image]

[Edit IndexedDB](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/indexeddb#edit)
[image]

Comment: It would still be editable as a user could just execute the edit command in the console directly. See [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/indexeddb) for Google help on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what ypu decribe is a JWT.
The token would contain this config and is signed with encryption, so the user won't be able to alter the config value without corrupting the token.

However, of course if you are doing this logic on the client side they could always find other ways of manipulating this.  E.g. intercepting your JavaScript and altering it never check permissions at all.

You will always be better off handling security server side, then you could choose to only serve these scripts to people who have paid for them.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a good idea. Would you mind telling me some sort of tutorial that I could try so I can learn how to do that? Thanks.